# Reading unicode characters from file/sqlite database and using it in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode

I have a list of variables with unicode characters, some of them for chemicals like Ozone gas: like 'O\u2083'. All of them are stored in a sqlite database which is read in a Python code to produce O<sub>3</sub>. However, when I read I get 'O\\u2083'. The sqlite database is created using an csv file that contains the string 'O\u2083' among others. I understand that \u2083 is not being stored in sqlite database as unicode character but as 6 unicode characters (which would be \,u,2,0,8,3). Is there any way to recognize unicode characters in this context? Now my first option to solve it is to create a function to recognize set of characters and replace for unicode characters. Is there anything like this already implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a byte string (length 7), decode the Unicode escape.

```
>>> s = 'O\u2083'
>>> len(s)
7
>>> s
'O\\u2083'
>>> print(s)
O\u2083
>>> u = s.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> len(u)
2
>>> u
u'O\u2083'
>>> print(u)
O₃
```

Caveat: Your console/IDE used to print the character needs to use an encoding that supports the character or you'll get a `UnicodeEncodeError` when printing.  The font must support the symbol as well.

Comment: @awulll: in most cases, `.decode('unicode-escape')` indicates a bug in your code (or upstream) -- do not use it -- it fixes surface symptoms while ignoring the core issue. For example, if the input format contains JSON text then the correct solution should use `json` module to parse it instead of `unicode-escape` -- there is not enough detail in your question to decipher what is your actual input format. SQLite can and should store a single Unicode character instead of the byte sequence -- fix the process that writes data to the database and/or cvs file.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, thanks for the comment. Your answer is useful too. For while, 'unicode-escape' help me cause is just a small point in all my stuff, but in the future I'll have to rewrite some SQLite databases and your advice will be considered! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

SQLite allows you to read/write Unicode text directly. `u'O\u2083'` is *two* characters `u'O'` and `u'\u2083'` (your question has a typo: `'u\2083' != '\u2083'`).

> I understand that u\2083 is not being stored in sqlite database as unicode character but as 6 unicode characters (which would be u,\,2,0,8,3)

Don't confuse `u'u\2083'` and `u'\u2083'`: the latter is a single character while the former is 4-character sequence: `u'u'`, `u'\x10'` (`'\20'` is interpreted as octal in Python), `u'8'`, `u'3'`.

If you save a single Unicode character `u'\u2083'` into a SQLite database; it is stored as a single Unicode character (the internal representation of Unicode inside the database is irrelevant as long as the abstraction holds).

On Python 2, if there is no `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of the module then `'abc'` string literal creates a bytestring instead of a Unicode string -- in that case both `'u\2083'` and `'\u2083'` are sequences of *bytes*, not text characters (`\uxxxx` is not recognized as a unicode escape sequence inside bytestrings).

Comment: I edited now. Was my fault. Is \u2083! Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember everything is bytes. To pull bytes into something useful to you, you kind of have to know what encoding is used when you pull in data. There are too many ambiguous cases to determine encoding by analyzing the data. When you send data out of your program, it's all back out to bytes again. Depending on whether you're using Python 2.x or 3.x you'll have a very different experience with Unicode and Python.

You can, however attempt encoding and simply do a "replace" on errors. For example `the_string.encode("utf-8","replace")` will try to encode as utf-8 and will replace problems with a `?` -- You could also anticipate problem characters and replace them beforehand, but that gets unmanageable quickly. Take a look at [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes) classes for more replacement options.

Comment: thanks, but the point is in my case I have just unicode, but '\u2083' is 6 characters and not just one, as I need. What I need is to convert one string with 6 characters ('\u2083') to one unicode character (\u2083, the small 3 in Ozone) and do this to any other character. I can do a function with a unicode table and do some replaces when necessary, but if there is another way to manage it would be nice.